# "Could not open lock file" and "Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock" when installing wget

Tags: debian

Ive been going at this for a few hours now. I am installing wget using the command

`sudo apt -y install wget`

and all I get at the end is the error "Unmet dependencies"

the unmet dependencies are: Could not open lock file and Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock

all other threads say to put sudo at the front of the command which I am clearly doing... what else can i do?

Comment: Do you have another instance of the package management tools running? If you run `pgrep apt` and `pgrep dpkg`, what do you get? Or is your filesystem in read-only mode? Check with `grep "ro," /proc/mounts`. (In Debian 10, `/sys/fs/cgroup` is supposed to be read-only, ignore it.)

Comment: `pgrep apt` returns nothing

Comment: `pgrep dpkg` returns nothing

Comment: `grep "ro," /proc/mounts` returns `tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0/dev/sr0 /media/jacob/VBox_GAs_6.0.10 iso9660 ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1000,gid=1002,dmode=500,fmode=400 0 0`